# Detecting Silent Switch in iOS 7 issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ios7

I am using following code to check iPhone silent switch is ON or OFF :-

```
if (self)
   {
    self.detector = [SharkfoodMuteSwitchDetector shared];
    CheckInViewController* sself = self;
    self.detector.silentNotify = ^(BOOL silent)
       {
        [sself.silentSwitch setOn:silent animated:YES];
      };
   }
```

It works fine in iOS 6 and below but in iOS 7 it always gives TRUE value. So, Please any one tell, how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you connect this code through IBAction in xib or storyboard?

Comment: @karthika:- No, above code have written in viewDidLoad and then in button action check silentSwitch is on or off.

Comment: check if button action connect by TouchUpInside or ValueChanged? I'm also facing this issue in IOS7.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work in iOS 7, and it never really worked in iOS 6 if you look at why it doesn't work in iOS 7.  This solution is based on the same code, so all credit to the original author though.

1. Keep `mute.caf` from your SharkfoodMuteSwitchDetector.
2. Create a new class, called HASilentSwitchDetector (or whatever), or replace the code in SharkfoodMuteSwitchDetector.

In the header file:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

typedef void(^HASilentSwitchDetectorBlock)(BOOL success, BOOL silent);

@interface HASilentSwitchDetector : NSObject

+ (void)ifMute:(HASilentSwitchDetectorBlock)then;

@end
```

In the implementation file:

```
#import "HASilentSwitchDetector.h"

void MuteSoundPlaybackComplete(SystemSoundID ssID, void *clientData)
{
    //Completion
    NSDictionary *soundCompletion = CFBridgingRelease(clientData);

    //Mute
    NSTimeInterval interval = [soundCompletion[@"interval"] doubleValue];
    NSTimeInterval elapsed = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - interval;
    BOOL isMute = elapsed < 0.2; // mute.caf is .2s long...

    //Then
    HASilentSwitchDetectorBlock then = soundCompletion[@"then"];
    then(YES, isMute);

    //Cleanup
    SystemSoundID soundID = [soundCompletion[@"soundID"] integerValue];
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(soundID);
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
}

@implementation HASilentSwitchDetector

+ (void)ifMute:(HASilentSwitchDetectorBlock)then
{
    //Check
    if ( !then ) {
        return;
    }

    //Create
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"mute" withExtension:@"caf"];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    if ( AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &soundID) == kAudioServicesNoError ) {
        //UI Sound
        UInt32 yes = 1;
        AudioServicesSetProperty(kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound, sizeof(soundID), &soundID,sizeof(yes), &yes);

        //Callback
        NSDictionary *soundCompletion = @{@"then" : [then copy], @"soundID" : @(soundID), @"interval" : @([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])};
        AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, MuteSoundPlaybackComplete, (void *)CFBridgingRetain(soundCompletion));

        //Play
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    } else {
        //Fail
        then(NO, NO);
    }
}

@end
```

Use like so:

```
[HASilentSwitchDetector ifMute:^(BOOL success, BOOL silent) {
    if ( success ) {
        if ( ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:forKey:kHasShownMuteWarning] && silent ) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kHasShownMuteWarning];
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[@"Mute Warning" localized] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:[@"This %@'s mute switch is on.  To ensure your alarm will be audible, unmute your device." localized], [[[UIDevice currentDevice] isiPad]? @"iPad" : @"iPhone" localized]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:[@"Ok" localized], nil] show];
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Of course, it looks like in your case you are depending on the repeated callback, so you'll have to reimplement that functionality (which I found to be a waste).  A simple timer calling ifMute: every second would suffice, and be no more wasteful than the original infinite-playback loop employed in the previous pattern.

Comment: This worked great for me. Thank you so much :)
Bonus: This also seems to drastically reduce the quiet *hiss* when the phone isn't silenced (at least on an iPhone 5s).